# If $f^{-1}(A)=A$ a.e. then show there is $B$ with $f^{-1}(B)=B$

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

> $f$  is a measurable mapping on $(X,\mu)$, and is measure-preserving, i.e.  for all measurable set $E$ , $\mu (f^{-1}(E))=\mu(E)$.
> There is a measurable set $A$，s.t. $f^{-1}(A) =A$ , a.e. which means $\mu(A\bigtriangleup f^{-1}(A))=0.$
>
> Then there exists $B$ measurable  s.t. $A=B$ , a.e. and $f^{-1}(B)=B$ .

I find this problem is similar to Poincare's Theorem, but I was not able to imitate its proof. I tried to let $B= A \cap f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-2}(A)\cdots$ but failed.

Comment: Something is missing in the question. The question as currently stated has a trivial answer: just note that $f^{-1}(X)=X$. We don't need $f$ to be measure-preserving and not even a measurable function.

Comment: But we need A=B,a.e. X may not meet the requirement

Comment: No. We don't need. 1. The conclusion "There exists a measurable set $A$，s.t. $f^{-1}(A) =A$ , a.e." is trivial, because $f^{-1}(X) =X$ and so $f^{-1}(X) =X$ a.e.. So, just take $A=X$. 2. The conclusion "there is $B$ measurable  s.t. $A=B$ , a.e. and $f^{-1}(B)=B$" is also trivial, because, since $A=X$, take $B=A=X$. So, we have $A=B$, and so, $A=B$ a.e. and we obviously have $f^{-1}(B)=B$, because $B=X$.

Comment: But $A$ is given in this question , it's fixed.  If $A=X$ , of course we can take $B=X$ as you say. But $A$ may not always be $X$.

Comment: Ok. I see.  The way the question is currently written it seems that the result  to be proved is: "$f$  is a measurable mapping on $(X,\mu)$, and is measure-preserving, i.e.  for all measurable set $E$ , $\mu (f^{-1}(E))=\mu(E)$.
There exists a measurable set $A$，s.t. $f^{-1}(A) =A$ , a.e. which means $\mu(A\bigtriangleup f^{-1}(A))=0.$"   and that the existence of  $B$ is just part of your strategy to prove the result.

Comment: It would be clearer if you write something like:  "Let $f$  be a measurable mapping on $(X,\mu)$, and is measure-preserving, i.e.  for all measurable set $E$ , $\mu (f^{-1}(E))=\mu(E)$. Suppose there exists a measurable set $A$，s.t. $f^{-1}(A) =A$ , a.e. which means $\mu(A\bigtriangleup f^{-1}(A))=0.$
Prove: $\exists B$ measurable  s.t. $A=B$ , a.e. and $f^{-1}(B)=B$."

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:** Try instead $B:=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{k=n}^\infty f^{-k}(A)$.